# SQLite Exception when creating table using OData object containing reference to itself

Tags: c#, sqlite, sharepoint-2010, windows-8, windows-runtime

The following code:

```
oc.CreateTablesAsync(typeof(ODataService.UserInformationListItem), typeof(ODataService.CategoriesItem), typeof(ODataService.PostsItem));
```

Gives me this exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about ODataApp.ODataService.UserInformationListItem
```

At first I was just creating a table for PostsItems, which is the object i need to store, but then I got the above exception but then for ODataApp.ODataService.CategoriesItem.

Since PostItem has the property Category, which is a List<CategoriesItem> I figured I had to add CategoriesItem as a table as well.

After doing so I got an error for the property CreatedBy on PostsItems, which is a UserInformationListItem, now this is when it gets tricky.

I also added UserInformationListItem to the CreateTables function which gave me my current problem.

The object UserInformationListItem also contains a CreatedBy property which is also an UserInformationListItem.

I'm looking for a way around this without having to alter or recreate local versions of these objects.

These objects are defined on Sharepoint which I cannot edit, and are obtained by the OData service reference. If anymore information is needed to supply me with an answer, please let me know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on your sample code I presume you're using [sqlite-net](http://nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net).

Sqlite-net is not a real ORM - it only has support for basic data types and can't handle your custom types as properties. You can check it your self in `SqlType()` static method of `Orm` class (`SQLite.cs`).

It's not self referencing that's causing problems, it's any references between the classes. Creating tables for the following two classes will fail as well with `NotSupportedException`:

```
public class CategoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class PostItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public List<CategoryItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

You'll need to create your own "database" classes which will map to database tables one-to-one. To handle `UserInformationListItem` you'll just add it's key value as a property to `PostItem`. If `PostItem` and `CategoryItem` have a many to many relationship you'll need to add a cross-reference table as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I was hoping it was solvable without having to create my own classes but I guess there's no other option.